# Indentação de código C

Tags: c, codeblocks, indentação

Eu e mais duas pessoas estamos desenvolvendo um código em C, e cada um fez a sua parte do código, porém ficou muito "bagunçado", existe algum comando para o codeblocks, a IDE que estamos usando, ou algum site que alinhe o código automaticamente?
Desde já, grato.

Answer (score 5):

### Indentação

Pode indentar no CodeBlocks acedendo a:

Plugins > Source code formatter(AStyle)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Atalhos

Pode também associar uma atalho à indentação através de:

Settings > Editor > Keyboard shortcuts > Source code formatter(AStyle)

Depois em `New Shortcut` configura o atalho que quer e faz `Add`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Configurações da indentação

É até possível de configurar a forma como o indentação é aplicada em:

Settings > Editor > Source formatter

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quer ao nível do estilo, indentação em tabs ou em espaços, *keywords* a não indentar, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o Notpad++ usando TextFX> TextFX Edit> Reindent C++ code.

Ou utilizar o Sublime Text.

```
http://substanciando.blogspot.com.br/2014/02/indentacao-no-sublime-text.html
```